# AttributeError on signals.py when combine user and profile

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-signals, django-errors

after combined User with Custom Profile on the register template forms included with signals.py to synchronization with User models.  The knowledge base was given the solution to add related_name to the models.py on OnetoOneFiedld and the issue still remains.

```
    AttributeError at /createuser
'User' object has no attribute 'profile'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/createuser
Django Version: 3.1.2
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'User' object has no attribute 'profile'
Exception Location: D:\Dev\main0\main\accounts\signals.py, line 16, in update_profile
Python Executable:  D:\Dev\main0\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.5
Python Path:    
['D:\\Dev\\main0\\main',
 'D:\\Dev\\main0\\venv\\Scripts\\python38.zip',
 'c:\\python38\\DLLs',
 'c:\\python38\\lib',
 'c:\\python38',
 'D:\\Dev\\main0\\venv',
 'D:\\Dev\\main0\\venv\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Sun, 01 Nov 2020 14:34:42 +000
```

I try to find out what is the root cause for an error
Here is the Signals.py file

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User) 
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User) 
def update_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created == False:
        instance.profile.save()
```

and the views.py

```
def CreateUser(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    first_name = request.POST['first_name']
    last_name = request.POST['last_name']
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password1']
    repassword = request.POST['password2']
    email = request.POST['email']

    if password == repassword:
        if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
            messages.error(request, f'User {username} already existed!!!')
            return redirect('register-page')
        elif User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            messages.error(request, f'email {email} already existed!!!')
            return redirect('register-page')
        else:
            user = User.objects.create_user(
                username=username, 
                password=password, 
                email=email, 
                first_name=first_name, 
                last_name=last_name
                )
            user.save()
            profile = Profile.objects.create(
                gender=gender,
                date_of_birth=date_of_birth,
                phone_number=phone_number,
                photo=photo
                )
            profile.user = user
            profile.save()           
            messages.success(request, f'User {username} has been created successfully!!')
            return redirect('main-users-page')
    else:
        messages.info(request,'password does not match')
        return redirect('register-page')
else:
    return render(request, 'registration/register.html')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution to add detail on signals.py

```
    @receiver(post_save, sender=User) 
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
        

    post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)
    
    @receiver(post_save, sender=User) 
    def update_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created == False:
            instance.profile.save()
            print('Profile updated!!')
    
    post_save.connect(update_profile, sender=User)
```